# get the objects of model refrenced in another model as fk django

Tags: python, django

How to get list of objects who has foriegn key in another model

```
Ex:
class A:
     field1
     field2

class B:
     field1 = fk to A
     field2
```

i want to get the list of objects of class A who has fk objects present in class B.
i dont want to get objects for class A whose fk is not available in class B. And is it possible to get in one query?

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now but probably something like:

```
as_in_bs = map(lambda b: b.field1, B.objects.filter(field1__isnull=False))
```

Take a look in their [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects) for more ideas.

Comment: It is the parameter for the lambda function. filter returns a queryset, which can be treated as a list.